# What is the difference between GLEW_VERSION_x_x and GL_VERSION_x_x?

Tags: c++, opengl, version, glew, mesa

I've always checked supported OpenGL version by running:

```
if (GLEW_VERSION_3_0)
```

This seemed to work fine until I tried it on another computer. This computer is running Fedora 19 and the glewinfo executable reports up to version 4.0. However GLEW_VERSION_3_0 is false. I switched the keyword to GL_VERSION_3_0 and that seems to work better.

So what is the difference between these to variables?

Comment: Could it be this bug? http://sourceforge.net/p/glew/bugs/104/

Comment: Oh.. yes. Quite possibly. But if I were to check that atleast one of GLEW_VERSION_3_0 or GL_VERSION_3_0 is true, would that be sufficient/safe?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you should ask on the Glew user forum what the exact meaning of these defines is?